# Determine whether $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: linear-algebra

The homework question states: Given a vector space $V$ and a subset $U$, determine whether $U$ is a subspace of $V$? And

$ V = {\mathbb{R}^n}{\text{ }}\left( {{\text{where }}n \in \mathbb{N}} \right);\;U = \left\{ {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{x_1}} \\ 
   {{x_2}} \\ 
   \vdots  \\ 
   {{x_n}} 
   \end{array}} \right)\left| {{x_1} \leqslant {x_2} \leqslant  \ldots  \leqslant {x_n}} \right.} \right\} $.

Since this is my first exposure to Linear Algebra 1, I unfortunately do not know how to start out with this question.

I have thought of: First choosing any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ e.g. $3$, but I'm not sure if I should then choose specific $x_1,x_1$ and $x_3$ for $u,v\in U$ such that ${x_1} \leqslant {x_2} \leqslant {x_3}$ for example $1 \leqslant 2 \leqslant 3$ and $4 \leqslant 5 \leqslant 6$ and then proceed with checking if $\underset{\raise0.3em\hbox{$\smash{\scriptscriptstyle-}$}}{0}  \in U$ and if $U$ is closed under addition and closed under scalar multiplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the right idea: check if $U$ is closed under addition or scalar multiplication. For example, if $n=3$, the vector $(1,2)$ is in $U$. Is every scalar multiple of this vector also in $U$?

It's a good idea to choose $n=3$ for now, just to get an idea of how the argument works. Then think about how to extend your argument to work for general $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the primary checks we need to make to show its a subspace. I will explain them in words as opposed to symbols to see if you can get an intuitive idea behind them

First, is the sum of any two vectors in your space also in your space?

Second, is the vector of all $0$'s in your space?

Third, can you multiply any vector by a scalar and stay in your space? (this one often tricks people; remember to multiply by both positive and negative numbers)

There are other things that vector spaces require, but they often come for free from the fact that the real numbers behave nicely. These I find are the three biggest things to check. So with this in mind, do all of these properties hold?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $(-1,1,...,1)\in V$ and $-2(-1,1,...,1)=(2,-2,...,-2)∉ V$ and hence $V$ is not closed under scalar multiplication and hence not a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$